# Given string format to date

Tags: javascript, date

I have given a very unusual date format in `string`. I need to convert it to a JS date object and add up a few days. The last step is clear, but I don't know how to convert the string into the JS date object. Take a look at the string date: `October 02, 2016`

Comment: `datestr.match(/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/)` and go from there?

Comment: Take a look at momentjs, it has some nice functions to do things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Syntax:

```
moment(dateString, format, locale)
```

```js
var dateStr = "Oktober 02, 2016"
var d = moment(dateStr, "MMM DD, YYYY", 'de');
console.log(d.format("DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you. The other answers are surely good as well, but I searched for a good JS framework like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `new Date()` can be converted from string to date.
And using `setDate()` you can add days in the date and can convert the date back to string,
Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var someDate = new Date('October 02, 2016');
console.log(someDate);
console.log(new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 5)).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse()` to parse the date and get the `Date` object.

```
var dateObj = new Date('October 02, 2016')
```

Now, you can perform all the `Date` operations on `dateObj`

Comment: You are missing Language too.

Answer (score 0):

Given that everything is static here, I thing the best case for you might be to keep a `map` of your month's name against there number i.e say `Oktober : 8`. This way you will easily get around of any `locale` issue in any library.

Once above map is done, you can use .substring to separate your string for `blank space` and `commas`  to get `date` and `year` easily.

Once you have all this you can use `new Date` constructor with months date and year field.

Hope this all is easily understood, so I am skipping any code here.